# filters.FilterSet with a custom field that is not in the model

Tags: django, django-filter, django-registration

```
class SomeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    id = NumberInFilter(field_name='id')
    name = StringInFilter(field_name='name')
    custom_field_that_is_not_in_model = filters.CharFilter()
```

This displays "[invalid name]:" because field `custom_field_that_is_not_in_model` is not in the Model (other fields work fine). How can I make it display what I want? I am going to call a custom method on this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`label`**---(`django-filter` doc)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html?highlight=label#label) option

```
class SomeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    field_in_model = filters.CharFilter(label='Your Cute Name')
```

Comment: yeah the problem with this it shows name `field_in_model` in admin. I want the name to be disaplayed as `custom_field_that_is_not_in_model`, and I don't want to create a new field in model just for this